# Why isn't this simple class garbage collected in Ruby console?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

I am running some tests with the Ruby garbage collector. When I run it from the Ruby console I get this weird behavior:

```
class B
end
#=> nil
count = ObjectSpace.each_object(B) {|x| x }
#=> 0
b = B.new
#=> #<B:0x00007feeb7849678>
count = ObjectSpace.each_object(B) {|x| x }
#=> 1
b = nil
#=>  nil
GC.start
#=> nil
count = ObjectSpace.each_object(B) {|x| x }
#=> 1
```

Why is it happening?

UPDATE: I only get this behavior in PRY. In IRB works as expected (the object is garbage collected).

Comment: From a black box perspective, this seems normal; the GC hasn't deemed it fit to destroy the instance in memory. Maybe it's waiting for a certain point in execution or for for some threshold to be hit, but regardless, it's out of your hands.

Comment: @ggorlen "...it's out of your hands" not necessarily. If you really want to force something to be collected you can technically [WeakRef](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html) it, although definitely not recommended as it could be consumed by an internal GC rather than an explicit `GC.start`. Simply adding `b = WeakRef.new(b)` before the `GC.start` causes this code to result in `0`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your example code works for me as expected, i.e. the last count returns `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was already answered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643390/gc-start-has-no-effect-in-pry-but-does-in-irb)

Pry stores the output of the last 100 commands and thus the object can't actually be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector only collects garbage when it absolutely has to. Collection is expensive.

Unless you run out of memory, it is highly unlikely that your object will be garbage collected.

Note: this is obviously highly dependent on the specific implementation, the specific version of the specific implementation, and the specific environment that you use. E.g. Rubinius has a completely different GC than YARV has, which has a completely different GC than MRuby has. Even *within* YARV, the GC has changed significantly between versions. TruffleRuby, JRuby, IronRuby, MagLev, and Opal don't even have a GC at all, the rely on the underlying platform's memory management.